# Listview won't match_parent

Tags: android, listview

Here is the XML :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffa500"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/profile_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/essai_profil" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/portrait_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_portrait" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/education_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/education_icon" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/skills_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/skill_icon" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/langue_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/map_icon" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loisir_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dice" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/contact_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/contact_icon" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bubble_1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_start" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bubble_2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_start"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bubble_3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_start"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bubble_4"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_start"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bubble_5"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_start"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bubble_6"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_start"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bubble_7"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_start"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bubble_patched" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textColor="#996300"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The listview takes only about a quarter of the linear layout remaining height.

As an experience I tried to use it alone (removing the textview and the linear layout) and it stretches as expected.

Might be stupid but cannot figure it out ...

Comment: use a relative layout

Comment: what's the text of your textview?

Comment: do you have any other outer layout?

Comment: giacomoni -> My name so pretty short !
Raghunandan -> I just tried, same behaviour

Comment: I put the whole code, sorry bout that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was all about the background of the linear layout "bubble_patched". Somehow it was cutting off at the patched part ... just came back to a non-9patched background as a solution.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

Add items in `listview` it will increase and scroll by default and make it `wrap_content`.

What is your exact problem? Question is not so clear.

Comment: My problem is that the listview won't go all the way to the bottom of its parent ... No matter what is inside.

Comment: add orientation vertical to parent Linear layout.

Comment: You mean the root linearlayout ? I figured out it was missing, I added it but still the same. By the way I set it to horizontal

Answer (score 1):

There must be some padding or something in your root layout otherwise it seems to Ok in my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DynamicListView" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="name"
            android:textColor="#996300"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of `Button` with `android:layout_height="100dp"`, they are taking all the height in your view.
14 `Button` with height 100dp = height 1400dp. And you also have a margin_top, that gets extra height to your view.

Comment: It is not suppose to bother, as these buttons are the first 2 column of the root linear layout, the listview being in the third

Comment: what's your screen size?

Comment: 800x1280 is the screensize

Comment: add android:layout_alignParentTop="true" to you textview and android:layout_below="@id/title" to your listview

Comment: still not ... That's one weird problem